# Upper index for logrank test comparing survival curves?

Tags: survival

The logrank test statistic for comparing survival curves is:

$$
Q = \frac{
    \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^m (d_{1i} - \hat{e}_{1i}) \right]^2
}{
    \sum_{i = 1}^m \hat{v}_{1i}
}
$$

I'm having trouble pinning down what the index $m$ is supposed to represent, but it's seems to be something like "the last row in your table where you have subjects remaining in both groups". I'm not sure if this is affected by censoring, e.g. if the last subject in one group is censored.

For simple example data (where 1 in the Event column represent an event and 0 right-censoring):

```
| Time| Event| Group|
|-----|------|------|
|  0.4|     1|     1|
|  1.2|     1|     0|
|  1.2|     1|     1|
|  3.4|     1|     0|
|  4.3|     1|     1|
|  4.9|     1|     1|
|  5.0|     0|     0|
|  5.0|     1|     1|
|  5.1|     1|     0|
|  5.1|     0|     1|
|  6.1|     1|     0|
|  7.1|     1|     0|
```

We have:

```
|   t| n_1| n_0| d_1| d_0| d_total| n_total|    ehat_1|    vhat_1|
|---:|---:|---:|---:|---:|-------:|-------:|---------:|---------:|
| 0.4|   6|   6|   1|   0|       1|      12| 0.5000000| 0.2500000|
| 1.2|   5|   6|   1|   1|       2|      11| 0.9090909| 0.4462810|
| 3.4|   4|   5|   0|   1|       1|       9| 0.4444444| 0.2469136|
| 4.3|   4|   4|   1|   0|       1|       8| 0.5000000| 0.2500000|
| 4.9|   3|   4|   1|   0|       1|       7| 0.4285714| 0.2448980|
| 5.0|   2|   4|   1|   0|       1|       6| 0.3333333| 0.2222222|
| 5.1|   1|   3|   0|   1|       1|       4| 0.2500000| 0.1875000|
| 6.1|   0|   2|   0|   1|       1|       2| 0.0000000| 0.0000000|
| 7.1|   0|   1|   0|   1|       1|       1| 0.0000000|       NaN|
```

And correctly calculating the test statistic (to match the answer provided by software packages) requires summing up to and including the row where $t = 5.1$. Figuring this out required a bit of trial and error on my part, so it would be great if someone could explain the rule that determines the upper index $m$ to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index $m$ is the number of distinct event time points in the data set. As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-rank_test), the test statistic is a standardized version of "observed - expected" events at every time point.